# Unable to get swagger UI screen in spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I configured swagger UI but I couldn't see the screen, I'm getting a 404 error, can anyone tell me how to solve the problems?

maven dependency's

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

SwaggerConfig file

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket apiDocket() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();
    }

}
```

Error image screen
[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this config

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.*;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.SecurityContext;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    public static final String SWAGGER_SCAN_BASE_PACKAGE = "notificationservice.web";

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Docket docket =  new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(SWAGGER_SCAN_BASE_PACKAGE))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
        return docket;
    }

    public ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Notification Service API")
                .description("Notification Service API Documentation")
                .license("Aapche 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://github.com/dvsigh9/licence")
                .build();
    }

    private SecurityContext securityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*")).build();
    }

    private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
        final AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
        final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[]{authorizationScope};
        return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("Bearer Token", authorizationScopes));
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Bearer Token", "Authorization", "header");
    }

}
```

Comment: same config but not working for me

Comment: in case you are using spring security then exclude swagger-ui uri

Answer (score 0):

swagger version 3.0.0 has changed the url to
/context-path/swagger-ui/
or /context-path/swagger-ui/index.html

This documented on the swagger-ui github
https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#migrating-from-existing-2-x-version

Answer (score 0):

you have to add only this dependency,and **Remove** `@EnableSwagger2`,after check it out url ../swagger-ui/index.html

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```